# Close button isn't working for react-bootstrap modal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to show another component using the react-bootstrap modal and react state. I'm following a react-bootstrap modal code and trying to customize the state my own way. I am able to create the state to open the modal without using React.useStae. But the problem is the modal isn't closing when I click the close button. So, How can I fixe this problem with the state?

This is the react-bootstrap modal code that I'm following:

[image: react-bootsrap-modal code]

and this is my code where I'm trying to open another component inside the modal. but the close btn is not working:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
//COMPONENTS
import { Container, Row, Col, Modal, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import FeatureCard from "../../widgets/ShoppingCards/FeatureCard/FeatureCard";
import AllDressHeader from "../../widgets/AllDressHeader/AllDressHeader";
import ProductCard from "../../widgets/ShoppingCards/ProductCard/ProductCard";
import Slider from "react-slick";

//Images
import ShirtHeader from "../../../assets/Shirts/header-new.jpg";
import img from "../../../assets/Shirts/A-unsplash.jpg";
import img2 from "../../../assets/Shirts/ocean-shirt.jpg";
import img3 from "../../../assets/Shirts/L-unsplash.jpg";
import img4 from "../../../assets/Shirts/denim.jpg";
import img5 from "../../../assets/Shirts/R-unsplash.jpg";
import img6 from "../../../assets/Shirts/P-denim.jpg";
import img7 from "../../../assets/Shirts/Q-unsplash.jpg";
import img8 from "../../../assets/Shirts/Y-unsplash.jpg";
import img9 from "../../../assets/Shirts/Mens-Popover.jpg";
import img10 from "../../../assets/Shirts/blur-shirt.jpg";
import shirts from "../../../assets/Shirts/A-unsplash.jpg";

class Shirts extends Component {
  state = {
    whichComponentToShow: "FeatureCard",
    show: false,
    setShow: false,
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ whichComponentToShow: "ProductCard", show: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {this.setState({setShow:false})};
  handleShow = () =>{this.setState({setShow:true})};

  render() {
    const featureCard = (
      <FeatureCard
        OnClick={this.onClick}
        image={img}
        title="Sky Blue"
        price="9$"
      />
    );
    const productCard = (
      <ProductCard image={shirts} title="Sky Blue" price="9$" add="shirt" />
    );

    //WHICH COMPONENT TO SHOW
    const ShowComponent = () => {
      if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === "FeatureCard") {
        return <div>{featureCard}</div>;
      } else if (this.state.whichComponentToShow === "ProductCard") {
        return (
          <div>
            <Modal
              show={this.state.show}
              onHide={this.handleClose}
              centered
              size="xl"
            >
              <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <Container fluid>
                  <Row>
                    <Col lg={12}> {productCard}</Col>
                  </Row>
                </Container>
              </Modal.Body>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                  Close
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

   
    return (
      <div className="Shirts" style={{ margin: "3rem 0rem" }}>
        <div>
          <AllDressHeader
            Image={ShirtHeader}
            h1="SHIRTS FOR MEN"
            para="Id adipisicing elit adipisicing Lorem. Laborum deserunt laboris ex aliqua deserunt ipsum irure culpa pariatur in esse esse quis. Laboris incididunt enim velit reprehenderit irure. Do est deserunt sint."
            h2="CHOOSE YOUR FAVOURITE SHIRT NOW"
          />
        </div>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <div>{ShowComponent()}</div>

            <Col>
              <FeatureCard image={img2} title="Beach Light" price="25.50$" />
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <div>
                <FeatureCard
                  image={img3}
                  title="Official Formal"
                  price="9.99$"
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <div>
                <FeatureCard image={img4} title="Denim" price="19$" />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <div>
                <FeatureCard image={img5} title="Red Black" price="12$" />
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <div>
                <FeatureCard
                  image={img6}
                  title="Blue White Denim"
                  price="56$"
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <div>
                <FeatureCard
                  image={img7}
                  title="White Long Sleeve"
                  price="8$"
                />
              </div>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <div>
                <FeatureCard image={img8} title="Blue Dotted" price="9.50$" />
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Shirts;
```

Comment: Why are using `setShow`? You already have `show` to manage the state and in `handleClose`, you just need to set that one to `false`:   `handleClose = () => {this.setState({show:false})};`

Comment: thanks that worked. but now another problem appeared. actually when I click the feature card component the modal pops up but when I'm closing the modal the feature card component gets removed from the list, it doesn't show on the list.but i want to keep the featurecard component after closing the modal. so how can i solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your modal references this.state.show, but your handleCLose/Show functions are setting this.state.setShow.

instead you should set "show"

```
  handleClose = () => {this.setState({show:false})};
  handleShow = () =>{this.setState({show:true})};
```

the example you are looking at is a functional component, where setShow is a mutation method for a useState hook. You are working with a classBased component, which uses setState for mutating its state.

Comment: thanks that worked. but now another problem appeared. when the modal gets closed, the component <FeatureCard> itself gets removed from the list, I have 4 components in a row but it shows 3 after I close the modal. actually when I click the feature card component the modal pops up but when I'm closing the modal the featurecard component gets removed from the list, it doesn't show on the list. so how can i solve this problem? thanks