# React-Bootstrap ONLY Close Button Styling Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

For ALL the components I'm using with React-Bootstrap, all the styling is working EXCEPT for close buttons that are built into Modals, Alerts, etc. Examples below.

**Alert Component - Expected**

[image: There's a styled close button on the top right]

**Alert Component that I see**

[image]

**Modal Component - Expected**

[image]

**Modal Component that I see**

[image]

The same thing is happening for npm packages that I'm using that are built on top of React-Bootstrap, like [React-Bootstrap-Typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead).

These are the dependencies I'm using:

```
"bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
"react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.4"
```

I import Bootstrap CSS in my `index.js` file:

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I import React-Bootstrap in my files like this and everything works without a problem EXCEPT the close buttons.

```
import { Modal, Button, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

I'm not importing Popper.js or Bootstrap.js anywhere though. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

### Edits

Underneath is the button being rendered in the HTML DOM and the styles being applied. Strangely, there are no styles being applied for the `.close` class on the button (and no styles for this in `bootstrap.min.css`). Also, the majority of the styles related to the button visuals are from the `user agent stylesheet`

```css
/* From user agent stylesheet */
button {
    appearance: button;
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(239, 239, 239), rgb(59, 59, 59));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0em;
    font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
    padding: 1px 6px;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
}
/* The appearance, text-transform, cursor, and margin properties
are being over-riden by _reboot.scss below */

/* From bootstrap/scss/_reboot.scss */
[type=button]:not(:disabled), button:not(:disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* This style is being over-riden*/
[type=button], button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

button {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    text-transform: none
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  <span class="sr-only">Close alert</span>
</button>
```

Comment: This question is different from [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3431) because I've imported `bootstrap.min.css`. It's different from the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63327658/close-button-isnt-working-for-react-bootstrap-modal-component) because the close buttons are functional. They're just not styled.

Comment: are the style applied when you check in the inspector, overridden by something in your app?  The solution is there.

Comment: To add on to @Crocsx's comment: Please open your browser's inspector to inspect the close button and let us know what CSS rules are being applied, and what file(s) they reside in.

Comment: @Crocsx @kmoser Thank you for your suggestion! I've now made those edits. It seems to me that there's a `.close` class being applied to the button, but no rules for this in `bootstrap.min.css`. I'm going to see if maybe I need to import a different version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been answered before but I am posting a version independent solution.

### THE PROBLEM

*`react-bootstrap`* starts acting strangely when it is not matched with it's corresponding *`bootstrap`* version. In OP's case, the close button on an Alert component was not styled properly.

### THE SOLUTION

We need to make sure that the versions of the two libraries match. Look inside your `package.json` file and see what versions of `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` are installed.

##### *package.json*:

```json
{
  "name": "react-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "dependencies": {
    
    "bootstrap": "5.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.4.3"
    
    // these versions might not match!   
  
  }  
}
```

To find if your versions match, visit the https://react-bootstrap.github.io website and check the versions drop down on the right:

[image]

- `react-bootstrap@2` and above - `bootstrap@5`
- `react-bootstrap@1.6.1` and above - `bootstrap@4`
- `react-bootstrap@0.33.1` and above - `bootstrap@3`

To solve the problem in the given example, either downgrade to bootstrap version 4:

`npm install --save bootstrap@4` or `yarn add bootstrap@4`

**or** upgrade to react-bootstrap 2

`npm install --save react-bootstrap@2` or `yarn add react-bootstrap@2`

In my case upgrading to react-bootstrap didn't work as it introduced other issues, but I successfully downgraded to bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I had "bootstrap": "^5.0.1" and "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.0" installed. I uninstalled react-bootstrap and then bumped up to "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-alpha.2", the close button got the proper styling.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it with this CSS:

```css
.close ::before{
    content: 'X';
    visibility: visible;
    color: "black";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.sr-only::before{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.close{
    /*background-color: red; */
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 32px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(247, 12, 12, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had `"bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1"` installed. I needed `"bootstrap": "^4.5.3"` with `"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0"`.

I uninstalled version 5 of bootstrap with npm. Installed version 4.5.3. Closed my terminal, restarted it again, and ran `run start`. Then, the styles were working as expected.

Comment: yes - just upgrading did not work for me - I needed to uninstall first.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem and I solved this. You need to add import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; you no need to uninstall bootstrap 5.

Comment: Please update and add more to illustrate what the OP has that is in error: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`